# Getting Id from programmatically view

Tags: java, android, android-view

This is a sample try code. I am adding checkbox and textview in the table row by using loop. Everything is working fine except that whenever I am trying to take out(checkBox, Textview) from another method, I am not able  to get it. I don't know how to solve this. I tried setId but I couldn't get the Id.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    TableRow[] row = new TableRow[5];
    TextView tv[] = new TextView[5];
    CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[5];
    Button clickTestRow;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j ++){
        row[j] = new TableRow(this);
        tl.addView(row[j]);
        tv[j] = new TextView(this);
        cb[j] = new CheckBox(this);

        tv[j].setText("This is text");

        row[j].addView(cb[j]);
        row[j].addView(tv[j]);

        if(j == 0)
            cb[j].setChecked(true);

    }

    clickTestRow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickTestRow);

    clickTestRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    TableLayout tlid = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
                if(cb[i].isChecked()){
                    tlid.removeView(row[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should move `TableLayout tl` to a field at the top of your class. Then you can use that variable within your onClickListener.

Comment: If i move it on the top, then I will get NPE, which I don't know why, but this way seems to fix it.

Comment: You'll still need to do `tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);`.

Comment: but I still need to get the id from checkbox so that I can remove the row. I did that, the NPE happens on the tableLayout line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but try this for now.

Key points here are

1. Fields for your views
2. Call `setContentView` **before** using `findViewById`
3. `final` variables for those that you are trying to use within an anonymous class (the onClickListener)

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TableLayout tl;
    private Button clickTestRow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        clickTestRow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickTestRow);

        final TableRow[] row = new TableRow[5];
        final TextView tv[] = new TextView[5];
        final CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[5];

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j ++){
            row[j] = new TableRow(this);
            tl.addView(row[j]);
            tv[j] = new TextView(this);
            cb[j] = new CheckBox(this);

            tv[j].setText("This is text");

            row[j].addView(cb[j]);
            row[j].addView(tv[j]);
        }
        cb[0].setChecked(true);

        clickTestRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
                    if(cb[i].isChecked()){
                        tl.removeView(row[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: now, I get what you mean. So by adding the final solve everything?

Comment: In this instance, yes. You could also move the arrays to fields and that would accomplish the same goal.

Comment: thank you so much. I got a hard time searching for ways to get Id